# Covering up PCB soldering pads

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

I have a PCB that I'm wanting to use just for stability purposes to hold other components.  Basically, I want to put a stacking header on it (for a Pi) and then hot glue some modules to the top and then use actual wires to connect them to the header.  However, the PCB I have has solder pads on both sides, and I don't want any accidental connections to be made.  Can I cover those with something non-conductive that will stick well, especially when I hot glue the components on?

[image: Components to attach]

Comment: yes, you can cover those ... it may be easier to get a board without copper

Comment: a job for kapon tape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of three options:

1. Use something like Kapton Tape to cover pads beneath the boards. This is strong tape which is both thermally and electrically insulating and commonly used as an insulator in electronics applications.
2. Buy either some bare perfboard or single-sided stuff - this is basically just board which is a grid of 0.1" holes but with either no copper on it or copper on just one side. That latter would still allow soldering on the reverse side, but be fully insulated on the top side. Single-sided perfboard is incredibly common and pretty cheap.
3. Make your own custom PCB for your design. Nowadays with the rise of PCB pooling companies (I shalln't name any), you can get PCBs made for barely a few $. You end up a board which is exactly what you need without lots of jumper wires, and the cost is no longer prohibitive.

Answer (score 5):

As a final option, you might just remove the solder pads.

You need a drill bit the same diameter (or a smidge larger) as the pads.  Twist the bit a few times on each pad, and it'll come right off.  It only takes a couple of seconds per pad.

I did that with the circuit board you see below.  That's a voltage doubler to generate 3000VDC out of 1200VAC.

I built it on a piece of perf board, using the pads to attach the parts to the board.  When all the parts were in place and soldered together, I removed all the unused pads with a drill bit by hand.

The standard perf board spacing is close enough together that I was concerned about the AC or DC jumping multiple pads to cause a short circuit - especially since the board will probably collect dust over the years.  It is part of the high voltage power supply in my oscilloscope, and I don't want it to go "Bang!" (again) when I'm using it.

[image]